# during maven build [mvn install] dependencies not getting downloaded from repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I am new to pom but went through the "Getting started" on maven.apache.org and also referred to an existing project within the company before i started on this project.

Info:
If i specify the jars as referenced libs in eclipse the project is running smooth and no issues are observed.

Problem: compilation errors since unable to download dependent code from repository.

My project structure is  [simplified for easier understanding]

```
utils
```

`utils/commons`  [has source in src/main/java style]  [uses package `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`]

```
utils/commons/pom.xml
```

`utils/pom.xml`  [parent]

Now I began with commons folder to write the pom.xml as the only module and no reference to any parent / other module.
After I ran `mvn install` it gave errors as

```
ToolUtils.java:[17,28] error: package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
ToolUtils.java:[18,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
```

If i commented the code which was using `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` then the `mvn install` works fine and generates a jar.
I looked up the net and found that the issue is failing to locate the repository so i updated the reference 
to parent pom.xml.
And also included the repositories details in the parent pom.xml. [which is directly under utils folder]

I am still getting the same error and the build does not move further.

```
ToolUtils.java:[17,28] error: package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
ToolUtils.java:[18,23] error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
```

I am using an internal URL which i have verified manually in a broswer.
Also I have verified that the proxy details are correct since another old project refers to the same URL and is getting built properly. 
[Unfortunately the project is far too complex to copy paste the pom.xml and modify , 
hence writing the pom.xml from scratch.]

Can some point what am i missing which causes no download from repository ?
Thanks in advance.
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Note: 
1) I am pasting snippets from the 2 different pom.xml with their directory names for easier identification. Attachments can be provided on request.
2) I have modified the references to confidential data across to protect some identities.

utils/common/pom.xml [commons module]

```
....
<parent>
    <groupId>com.osg.rtos</groupId>
    <artifactId>rxutils</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
....
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.osg.rtos</groupId>
            <artifactId>rtos-commons-service</artifactId>
            <version>${rtos.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

utils/pom.xml [parent]

```
....
<groupId>com.osg.rtos</groupId>
<artifactId>rxutils</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>rxutils</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>  


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>release</id>
        <url>http://internal.com/~devbuild/repository</url>         
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.osg.rtos</groupId>
            <artifactId>rtos-commons-service</artifactId>
            <version>${rtos.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.osg.rtos</groupId>
            <artifactId>rtos-data</artifactId>
            <version>${rtos.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.osg.rtos</groupId>
            <artifactId>rtos-exception</artifactId>
            <version>${rtos.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.osg.rtos</groupId>
            <artifactId>rtos-mailbox-service</artifactId>
            <version>${rtos.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.osg.rtos</groupId>
            <artifactId>rtos-message-service</artifactId>
            <version>${rtos.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.osg.rtos</groupId>
            <artifactId>rtos-rest</artifactId>
            <version>${rtos.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<modules>
    <module>commons</module>        
    <module>rxutils</module>        
    <module>tool</module>        
</modules>  
...
```

Comment: Showing actual Maven output would be helpful.

Comment: Jonathan's comment worked. Thanks a tonne. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `<dependencyManagement>` tags that surround the `<dependencies>` section in the commons module `pom.xml`.

The [`<dependencyManagement>`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) section allows you to specify dependency information, such as version number, in a parent pom (as you have done) so that you can simplify dependencies in the child poms. However, you still need a `<dependencies>` section to specify *what* dependencies are required for that child.

Answer (score 1):

in `pom.xml` use

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

remove or comment `<exclusions>` and `<exclusion>`